# Blank page added when table splits due to a page break using iText 5.5.7

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I had some code that worked with iText 2.1.7. We decided to move to the latest version of iText. I tested the code with version 5.5.6 and the code also worked perfectly.

When version 5.5.7 came out last month we decided to upgrade to that version as it had some fixes regarding performance when using nested tables and splitting rows that seemed relevant to the project.

However in some scenarios, a blank page is added to the PDF when the table splits due to a page break. As I said, the code works fine with iText 2.1.7 and iText 5.5.6.

Here is the code used to build the table:

```
    float[] widthsIllustration = { 0.75f, 8 };
    PdfPTable tableIllustration = ReportBuilderCommon.buildTable(2, 100, widthsIllustration);
    tableIllustration.setSplitLate(false);
    tableIllustration.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.BOTTOM);
    tableIllustration.getDefaultCell().setPaddingBottom(5);
```

The table above is nested in another table created like this

```
PdfPTable leftColumn = ReportBuilderCommon.buildTable(1, 100);
 leftColumn.setSplitLate(false);
```

Here is the method `buildTable`:

```
public static PdfPTable buildTable(final int numColums, final float widthPercentage) throws DocumentException {
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(numColums);
    table.setWidthPercentage(widthPercentage);
    table.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);

    return table;
}
```

Comment: The `tableIllustration ` does not seem to receive any input. Is that correct?

Comment: The code above isn't the complete code.

Comment: Can you provide enough self-contained code for reproducing the issue?

Comment: Sorry @mkl, the code has a lot of dependencies. Thanks for trying to help anyway. I posted the question just in case someone had seen the same issue using splitLate.

Comment: It might be some kind of regression but without reproducibility i cannot analyze it. But as you say, maybe someone else comes around and can provide a sample without such a bunch of dependencies.

Comment: We (iText Software) would like to investigate and fix this issue. A standalone sample to reproduce would be very helpful.